# Push based api design

Tags: http, websocket, server-sent-events

I'm designing a web API that will give an opprtunity for clients(other apps) to push some work request, receive immediately some id of that work request and later receive the result of that work request. 
What is the typical approach for such kind of interactions?
As providing the result of work request reminds me server push interaction I thought about SSE(server sent events) and webscoket technologies, inclinig to websockets(as client may use the same connection for all kind of requets and receive all kinds of response). Is it a good choice for my goal? and how this can be scaled?

Comment: Your question is much too broad IMO. Not voting to close since I'm not a web apps guy.

Comment: @einpoklum why so? The question is about whether websocket technology suits for the described approach of api design and if not I'm wondering what is a better approach.

Comment: @maks, software design questions fit in a different SO site, such as [this one](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com)... The StackOverflow community is for more practical based questions.

Comment: @Myst when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat - good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is about whether websocket technology suits for the described approach of api design and if not I'm wondering what is a better approach. Is it a good choice for my goal?

A webSocket connection is very well suited for receiving results back at some indeterminate time in the future and it would be a recommended way to do this.

Other requests from the client to server can either be ajax calls or sent as webSocket messages, mostly depending upon whether there are other reasons to make the requests as ajax calls or not.  If you already have an established webSocket connection, then it is a convenient, easy and fast way to communicate with the server.

Taking the individual parts of what you doing:

> Pushing some work request (from client to server).

This can be done equally well via Ajax or webSocket.  If there was no other reason to have an already established webSocket connection, then this would traditionally be an Ajax call.

> receive immediately some id of that work request

This is actually a little easier to do with an Ajax request because Ajax is a request/response protocol so if you send the work request via Ajax, it would be trivial to get the ID back as the response to that Ajax request.  You could also do it via webSocket, but webSocket is just a messaging protocol.  When sending the work request to the server, you could send it via a webSocket (as mentioned previously).  And, the server could then immediately send back the work ID, but the client would have to develop some way to correlate the work ID coming back with the previously sent request since those two messages would not have any natural connection to one another.  One way that correlation could be done is to have the client generate a temporary ID or hash value when sending the initial request (it can literally be anything that is unique for that client such as a timestamp) and then the server would send that same temporary ID back when it sends the work ID.  All this is trivial with a request/response protocol like HTTP/Ajax.

> later receive the result of that work request

HTTP Polling, webSocket or SSE could all be used.  Polling is obviously not particularly efficient.  I know a webSocket would work perfectly for this and it would provide an open conduit for any other items the server wants to send to the client in a push fashion.  SSE can also be used to solve this problem (pushing data to a client) though I don't personally have any experience with it.